# Can I rewrite this using Zend_Db_Select?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I need to write the following query:

```
SELECT forum_threads.id AS id_thread,
forum_threads.topic,
forum_threads.date_created,
forum_posts.content,
CONCAT(users.first, ' ', users.last) AS author_name 
  FROM forum_threads,forum_posts,users
     WHERE forum_threads.category_id=1
        AND forum_threads.author_id=users.id
        AND forum_posts.id=
            (SELECT id FROM forum_posts WHERE thread_id=`id_thread` ORDER BY date_posted ASC LIMIT 0,1)
```

I'm not asking anyone to do the work for me. I just couldn't find anything in the reference that could do a query like this. Point me in the right direction and that should be everything I need.

I can get to the point where I need to the subquery, then I have no idea how to progress. Any ideas?

FYI: I want to use a Zend_Db_Select object because I'm sending it to a Zend_Paginator

Clarification of what the query is doing: Pulling all threads for a given forum category a long with the content of the first post.

Comment: I know this question is old but just in case anyone is still reading this, Zend_Paginator now supports other adapters such as arrays so you don't need the Zend_Db_Select object :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I developed a lot of `Zend_Db_Select` while I worked for Zend, as well I wrote the docs and the unit tests.

My usual advice with `Zend_Db_Select` is that **you don't have to use it**.  It's meant to be used when you have complex application logic that *needs* to build up a query piece by piece.  If you already know the full SQL query, it's far easier to just execute it as a string and don't use `Zend_Db_Select` at all.

But to answer your query, I include a solution below.

I changed the query so that it doesn't need a subquery.  I'm using a trick with `LEFT  JOIN` to match the post `p` that has no other earlier post `p2` with the same `thread_id`.  This should be more efficient than the subquery idea you had.

```
$select = $db->select()
 ->from(array('t'=>'forum_threads'), array('id_thread'=>'id', 'topic', 'date_created'))
 ->join(array('p'=>'forum_posts'), 't.id=p.thread_id', array('content'))
 ->joinLeft(array('p2'=>'forum_posts'),
     't.id=p2.thread_id AND p.id > p2.id', array())
 ->join(array('u'=>'users'), 't.author_id = u.id',
     array('author_name'=>new Zend_Db_Expr("CONCAT(u.first, ' ', u.last)")))
 ->where('t.category_id = 1')
 ->where('p2.id IS NULL');
```

I test this and it has the following output:

```
SELECT `t`.`id` AS `id_thread`, `t`.`topic`, `t`.`date_created`, `p`.`content`,
  CONCAT(u.first, ' ', u.last) AS `author_name` 
FROM `forum_threads` AS `t`
 INNER JOIN `forum_posts` AS `p` ON t.id=p.thread_id
 LEFT JOIN `forum_posts` AS `p2` ON t.id=p2.thread_id AND p.id > p2.id
 INNER JOIN `users` AS `u` ON t.author_id = u.id 
WHERE (t.category_id = 1) AND (p2.id IS NULL)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I wouldn't normally use Zend_Db_Select to be honest, but the paginator needs that or a tableselect object in order to do the pagination for me.

Comment: Btw, I realized that there's one problem, if `date_created` has duplicates, you could get more than one row that seems to be the earliest.  If you can rely on the order of p.id corresponding to chronological order, you can use that instead and avoid the possibility of ties.